# Будет ли утечка памяти?

Tags: c, указатели, память

Допустим, есть код:

```
char * str = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(str, "simple_string");
str = strrem(str, "s_");
```

Функция `strrem`:

```
char * strrem(const char * _str, const char * _to_rem)
{
    char * out = malloc(strlen(_str) * sizeof(char));
    ...
    return out;
}
```

Что станет с первоначальным указателем `str` и указателем `out`?

Comment: Утечка будет. Сотрётся/потеряется указатель

Comment: Не видно free(), утечка будет...

Comment: Не очень понятно, чего в конечном итоге Вы хотите, но посмотрите на [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), как замену malloc/strcpy, также, может быть, `realloc` это именно то, что Вам нужно внутри `strrem()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте взглянем, что происходит с переменной `str` во время указанных манипуляций:

```
char * str = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));

/*     str
 *      v
 * +---------+
 * | 16 байт |
 * +---------+
 */
```

Пока все просто - выделили память под 16 байт.

```
strcpy(str, "simple_string");

/*     str
 *      v
 * +---------+
 * | 16 байт | = "simple_string"
 * +---------+
 */
```

На всякий случай, стоит использовать [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) чтобы не выйти за пределы памяти.

```
str = strrem(str, "s_");

/*      ?                              str
 *      v                               v
 * +---------+                     +---------+
 * | 16 байт | = "simple_string"   | 13 байт |
 * +---------+                     +---------+
 */
```

После этого шага `str` указывает на новую область памяти. Если внутри функции `strrem` не производится очистка памяти по переданному указателю (а это делать не стоит как минимум потому что туда могут передать указатель на область памяти на стеке), то произойдет утечка памяти.

---

*P.S.: Согласно стандарту Си, `sizeof(char)` **всегда** возвращает `1`*

Answer (score 4):

Буфер, первоначально выделенный под `str` не освобождается, а указатель на него меняется (теперь указывает на буфер-результат `strrem`). То есть теперь нет возможности освободить память и до конца жизни процесса она для нас "утекла".

Answer (score 2):

В этом примере есть ещё одна ошибка:

```
char * out = malloc(strlen(_str) * sizeof(char));
```

Вы забыли про \0 ! Надо так:

char * out = malloc(strlen(_str) * sizeof(char) + 1);

Comment: Тогда уж `(strlen(_str) + 1) * sizeof(char)`